# How to pass an anonymous function to dplyr summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, anonymous-function

I have a simple data frame with 3 columns: **name**, **goal**, and **actual**.
Because this is a simplification of much larger dataframe, I want to use dplyr to compute the number of times a goal has been met by each person.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c(rep('Fred', 3), rep('Sally', 4)),
                 goal = c(4,6,5,7,3,8,5), actual=c(4,5,5,3,3,6,4))
```

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

I should be able to pass an anonymous function similar to what is shown below, but don't have the syntax quite right:

```
library(dplyr)
g <- group_by(df, name)
summ <- summarise(g, met_goal = sum((function(x,y) {
                                       if(x>y){return(0)}
                                       else{return(1)}
                                     })(goal, actual)
                                    )
                  )
```

When I run the code above, I see 3 of these errors:

> Warning messages:
>     1: In if (x == y) { :
>       the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have equal length vectors in `goal` and `actual`, so the relational operators are appropriate to use here.  However, when we use them in a simple `if()` statement we may get unexpected results because `if()` expects length 1 vectors.  Since we have equal length vectors and we require a binary result, taking the sum of the logical vector is the best approach, as follows.

```
group_by(df, name) %>%
    summarise(met_goal = sum(goal <= actual))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    name met_goal
  <fctr>    <int>
1   Fred        2
2  Sally        1
```

The operator is switched to `<=` because you want `0` for `goal > actual` and `1` otherwise.

Note that you *can* use an anonymous function. It was the `if()` statement that was throwing you off. For example, using

```
sum((function(x, y) x <= y)(goal, actual))
```

would work in the manner you are asking about.

Comment: This answers the question well. I did overcomplicate my attempt intentionally because I wanted to see how a more complex/general anonymous function could be passes.

Comment: @MichaelSzczepaniak - Note that you *can* use an anonymous function.  It was the `if()` statement that was throwing you off.  For example, `sum((function(x, y) x <= y)(goal, actual))` would work.

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thanks for explaining this (twice ;-).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution using [`data.table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4):**

You asked for `dplyr` solution, but as actual data is much larger you can use `data.table`. `foo` is function you want to apply.

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
    res <- 0
    if (x <= y) {
        res <- 1
    }
    return(res)
}

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkey(df, name)[, foo(goal, actual), .(name, 1:nrow(df))][, sum(V1), name]
```

If you prefer pipes then you can use this:

```
library(magrittr)
setDT(df) %>%
    setkey(name) %>%
    .[, foo(goal, actual), .(name, 1:nrow(.))] %>%
    .[, .(met_goal = sum(V1)), name]

    name met_goal
1:  Fred        2
2: Sally        1
```

Comment: I haven't worked much with data tables, but am aware of their benefits so I'm sure I'll be using something like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself needing to do something similar to this again (a year later) but with a more complex function than the simple one provided in the original question.  The originally accepted answer took advantage of a specific feature of the problem, but the more general approach was touched on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730774/how-to-use-custom-functions-in-mutate-dplyr).  Using this approach, the answer I was ultimately after was something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(name = c(rep('Fred', 3), rep('Sally', 4)),
                 goal = c(4,6,5,7,3,8,5), actual=c(4,5,5,3,3,6,4))

my_func = function(act, goa) {
  if(act < goa) {
    return(0)
  } else {
    return(1)
  }
}

g <- group_by(df, name)
summ = df %>% group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(met_goal = sum(mapply(my_func, .data$actual, .data$goal)))

> summ
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name  met_goal
  <fct>    <dbl>
1 Fred         2
2 Sally        1
```

The original question referred to using an anonymous function.  In that spirit, the last part would look like this:

```
g <- group_by(df, name)
summ = df %>% group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(met_goal = sum(mapply(function(act, go) {
                                    if(act < go) {
                                      return(0)
                                    } else {
                                      return(1)
                                    }
                                  }, .data$actual, .data$goal)))
```